# Aspose.words : page break with a background color, what could it be?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.8, aspose, aspose.words

I am using the .NET version and I have a problem.

I am doing the following things:

- I have a source document with various styles
- I merge documents with same or different styles and importing them with KeepSourceFormatting and testing with KeepDifferentStyles but there is no difference.
- The problem appears with builder.InsertDocument , document.AppendDocument is not the right method for me, but AppendDocument does not show this problem
- I put Page Breaks when I need

with this, page breaks, have a shadow behind that looks like a style present in the document, but, if I check, Word tells me those empty paragraphs with page breaks does not have a style.

What could I check? Can I remove that shadow when I make the page break?

Thanks!

[image]

As you can see it says "Interruzione di pagina" which is "page break" in Italian

**Important edit:** putting a couple of empty writeln("") fix the problem, looks like the shadow on the page break was linked to the style of the next page which comes from another word merged.

```
docBuilderOrigine.Writeln("");                          
docBuilderOrigine.InsertBreak(BreakType.PageBreak);
docBuilderOrigine.Writeln("");
```

Comment: The question is answered in Aspose.Words support forum: https://forum.aspose.com/t/page-break-with-a-style-that-does-not-exist-while-merging-other-documents/271240/2